# Firebase function to reset value at a specific time of day

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I use the firebase realtime database to store user information.

Here is a picture of the database: [screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqbT2.png)

How can I reset the value "nombre_dons_day" for all the users each day at 00:00 using firebase fonctions ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: One approach could be using the cron-job website to trigger your http function each day at that time, but that service maybe is not that stable as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HAVE to use something other than Firebase cloud functions as a trigger... whether that's a 3rd-party chron job service, that's up to you. [This Firebase article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) addresses this issue and walks you through doing it with Google's App Engine... but whether you choose to use a Google-backed solution or a [well known 3rd-party service](https://cron-job.org/en/) is up to you.

The cron job should call/trigger your cloud function... and in your case, the cloud function should loop over all of the users in that database table and reset (*or add 1 to*) the "nombre_dons_day" field.